# What content type header to use for JSON? "application/json; charset=utf-8 " or "application/json"?

Tags: json, http, spring-mvc

It seems that the JSON default encoding is UTF-8 and Spring MVC returns  `application/json; charset=utf-8` by default, which is hard to change.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)

> JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is UTF-8.

It goes on to describe how the different UTF-* encoding are to be detecting, suggesting that no other encodings are supported.

"SHALL" represents an absolute requirement here (see [RFC 2119](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119)).

And there really is no reason to use a non-UTF encoding with JSON (as anything that can handle JSON can *definitely* handle UTF-8).

Comment: *anything that can handle JSON can definitely handle UTF-8* You'd think so wouldn't you. But alas, both [Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=438464&) and Firefox mess this up and interpret JSON as latin when no `charset` is provided in the Content-Type.

Comment: FWIW, Chrome and Firefox have long been fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a charset parameter on application/json is incorrect, as that media type does not define a charset parametert. See https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc8259.html#rfc.section.11, last sentence:

> Note: No "charset" parameter is defined for this registration. Adding one really has no effect on compliant recipients.