# Spring-boot app behaves differently with Content-Type: "application/json" vs Content-Type: "application/json;charset=UTF-8"?

Tags: json, utf-8, spring-boot

I was expecting that "application/json" and "application/json;charset=UTF-8" will behave same way considering that default encoding for jackson is UTF-8 but to my surprise it does not.

```
{"name":"test-生"}
```

Posting above data to simple spring-boot app with content-type="application/json" results in garbled data. What did I misunderstood?

I also came across several SO questions around this which seems to suggest my expectation was correct but doesn't seem to work.

I am on Spring-Boot = 1.3.5.Release

[What does "Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254891/what-does-content-type-application-json-charset-utf-8-really-mean/9254967#9254967)

[Why content type header to use for json? "application/json; charset=utf-8 " or "application/json"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814908/why-content-type-header-to-use-for-json-application-json-charset-utf-8-or)

Comment: Also, spring has default encoding of utf-8 as per doc.  So what am I missing? spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8 # Charset of HTTP requests and responses. Added to the "Content-Type" header if not set explicitly.
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true # Enable http encoding support.