# HttpContext.Response.ContentType is set by default as "application/json; charset=utf-8" - how to change this default?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm having an ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API system where I'm caching requests to replay them (an idempotency layer). On the response pipeline, I get a Content-Type header with the value `"application/json; charset=utf-8"`. But I see this question [What content type header to use for JSON? "application/json; charset=utf-8 " or "application/json"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814908/what-content-type-header-to-use-for-json-application-json-charset-utf-8-or) that says that this header value is not right.

Then, in practice I see that it actually is giving me problems, because when I replay the response with this header value that `SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter` is not found as a valid output formatter (It matches just `"application-json"` and not `"application-json; charset=utf-8"`).

Checking the source I see that `SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter` has [`SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.UTF8);`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/ec578d6b75c2dceae827add3498009bc76b58b5c/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Formatters/SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.cs#L28) as well as [`SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValues.ApplicationJson);`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/ec578d6b75c2dceae827add3498009bc76b58b5c/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Formatters/SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.cs#L30)

The only workaround I've found is to explicitly add this media type to the formatter like this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers(options => {
    var formatter = (TextOutputFormatter)options.OutputFormatters.
                    Where(o => o.GetType() == typeof(SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter)).First();
    formatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/json; charset=utf-8");
});
```

It's not working around the right problem, in my opinion.

How can I set the response default not to contain the charset?

Comment: Having to add a workaround for supporting a "application/json; charset=utf-8" Content-Type header on the request.

Comment: It is  already supported by default. You are the first who asks this

Comment: It can not be duplicate, because nobody asked this question before, since the question doesn' t make any sense.

Comment: I still argue that you are not trying to understand the question, because you would be asking about the question instead of concluding it doesn't make sense. I edited it to make it more clear, maybe you can understand it now?

Comment: The perfect is the enemy of the good. Nobody ever thought about this Forget about this unless you don't have anything else to do.

Comment: Why can't you do the same? Maybe someone else has an insight that you don't, but with -1, it's hard that someone will actually get to see it. I believe the question does make sense and is a legit question, whatever you think about what everyone else thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to change the response's `Content-Type` is using the Produces attribute like this:

`[Produces("application/json")]`

This is the cleanest option I've found so far.